# PHP/Apache - how to see script warnings before header redirects?

Tags: php, apache

I use a lot of header redirects but because of that I miss some PHP warnings that don't get shown due to redirect. Is there some PHP/Apache configuration option that would stop header redirects if any warnings are issued?

In fact I would like any warnings to stop script execution (like errors do) on my development machine but to be invisible on other servers - so that means some configuration setting and not changing of scripts. Is that possible? I'm using Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2

All warnings are displayed normally on my development server, but when they're followed by a header redirect, I can't see them. Example:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
unset($undef);
echo $undef; // generates warning, should stop redirect.
//exit; 
//when previous line is uncommented, I see the warning
header("Location: http://www.google.com"); // still happens, but shouldn't
exit;
?>
```

Comment: My suggestion in environments like that is to rely heavily on your error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your development servers put:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ob_start();
...

if(ob_get_length() > 0){
    ob_flush();
    exit();
}
header(...);
```

before your header redirects (as shown).  If anything is in the buffer it will be displayed and this will cause your header redirect to fail because it is impossible to do a header redirect if something has been rendered to the browser. If you turn `display_errors` to `Off` on your production servers, then these messages will not display.

Comment: I put this on top of the script and redirects still happen after warnings are generated. I echo some $undefinedvariable before the header() call and it generates a warning but header() still redirects.

Comment: Post the code you are having a problem with in your question.  If you think a warning is being generated, do an `exit()` before your `header()` to confirm your theory.

Comment: if I put an exit; before header() I see a warning. If there is no exit; then redirect happens as if the warning was not shown. That's how I usually check for warnings before redirect, by exit; just before the header() call but that's too much of a hassle to change and change back every time.

Comment: Please post what you are seeing to your question.  I cannot debug what I cannot see.

Comment: Done. All error reporting on my development server was enabled to begin with, it's just that warnings for some reason do not break header redirects.

Comment: Ok, that works, thanks. I'll have to add ob_flush() before any header call. Now I see that there's an implicit_flush config option, maybe I'll go with that. Anyway, thanks a lot. I couldn't find anything about this because every problem anyone has with warnings and header is exactly the opposite of what happened here.

Comment: That is really weird behavior.  I have had problems with header redirects with errors in the past.... don't understand why this particular example wasn't working, but that's life sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
//header("location: such-and-such");
```

lol, but really; its not more simple than that.